# Python - split one list to smaller lists conditionally

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

Consider following list

```py
all_values = [
    {"a": "first_type"},
    {"a": "second_type"}, {"a": "second_type"},
    {"a": "third_type"}
]
```

I would like to build a dict:

```py
sorted_objs = {
   "first": [{"a": "first_type"}],
   "second": [{"a": "second_type"}, {"a": "second_type"}],
   "third": [{"a": "third_type"}]
}
```

What I do:

```py
for obj in all_values:
    if obj["a"] == "first_type":
        sorted_objs["first"].append(obj)
    elif obj["a"] == "second_type":
        sorted_objs["second"].append(obj)
    elif obj["a"] == "third_type":
        sorted_objs["third"].append(obj)
```

I wonder how I can improve that? All_values list might be a little bit long so maybe I should think about performance too.

Comment: Look at `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: maybe reversing your data helps... 
inv_data =  [{v: k for k, v in i.items()} for i in data]

Comment: Are dicts of the same type always consecutive, as the two `second_type` in your example?

Comment: Do those strings always differ by that `_type` suffix?

Comment: @KellyBundy good questions "Are dicts of the same type always consecutive, as the two second_type in your example?" No. "Do those strings always differ by that _type suffix?" Sometimes the string is different and not related to one another at all (no common string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better look up `obj["a"]` with a dictionary instead of those if/else. Here I build one that maps it to the `append` method of the list it belongs in ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBCsIwEETv@xVLvLRYevEiBT9BPEuREm3UaE1CshGK9NtrklLswdxmZzJvE9PTXavN1thxXOFRe4tOkDfAu655884LhzusAcP5MM4qZFdpHTXUG8GGYmk4cdGqnZ3/02We7tLOBpzAaUuibfT5EZGfiRNy9amYW2aVbiYxAMAK9z063XmSWgE3Rqg2NiTWE9fIJkiFvJzc5Fy1xWeBHKXCBbuUJF4uy2Eob4IAYizMY@r3J1VqmMqy4NbhRWEx2eZR5WmpgyfjCYyVirIFIB/HLw)):

```
append = {
    k + "_type": a.append
    for k, a in sorted_objs.items()
}.get

for obj in all_values:
    append(obj["a"], id)(obj)
```

Using `id` to ignore keys that don't exist is a bit of a hack, you could do `ignore = id` or `def ignore(_): pass` and then use that to make it clearer.

Some more explanation:

Your code (under *"What I do:"*) means you must already have `sorted_objs = {"first": [], "second": [], "third": []}`. So I take advantage of that to prepare a helper dict where key `"first_type"` maps to the `append` method of the first list, etc. Then I go through your `obj`s and use my helper dict's `get` method to get the appropriate `append` method (or, corresponding to your non-existent `else` branch, a "fake" append function that has no effect). Then I call that to append (or ignore) the `obj`.

**Addendum for your comment:** If instead of "first" etc you have arbitrary names "X" etc, you need to specify that explicitly again, for example:

```
targets = [
    ("first_type", "X"),
    ("second_type", "Y"),
    ("third_type", "Z"),
]
```

The initial `sorted_objs` could be computed then, and my solution would become:

```
sorted_objs = {target: [] for _, target in targets}

append = {
    source: sorted_objs[target].append
    for source, target in targets
}.get

for obj in all_values:
    append(obj["a"], id)(obj)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBasQgEIbv8xSDe0lA9tJLCfQRSq/dBgl243YtQUXHQljy7KnGXeJhvajz/fP/Om6mqzUvr86v6wFPNnoMiqIDOU3Dn5yiCviGPWBaNyZZh@yifaCBZqfYwmsQ1Nma8UGeV2s9XbV/ABBA0v8o2uOaOokj@2Qtv4PaM5HTTirPBL4yEAAHfJ8x2CmStgaC9aTGwX7/5rBbye2wF3ixHgeOpYLa3E9hAemcMmOWb0EhDeqsOqys@qIVxyLdZNmvSJ@YwnJMG0AWJYNM9qF3W3@xahLt08gERz22@dZC/tNHJBcJnNeGmuol7br@Aw)

Comment: Thanks, nice solution. Would you like to try having other keys in the sorted_objs at all? Perhaps`sorted_objs = {"X": [<list of all objs where a is of first_type>], "Y": [<list of all objs where a is of second_type>], "Z": [<list of all objs where a is of third type>]}`. Provided help is already enough so it's just a question that can be left unanswered.

Comment: You mean same as in the question but with "X/Y/Z" instead of "first/second/third"?

Comment: Yes, exactly, arbitrary key names for the lists.

Comment: See the addendum.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of room for improvement, here's my suggestion:

-Add a list defining the desired order

```
all_values = [
    {"a": "first_type"},
    {"a": "second_type"}, {"a": "second_type"},
    {"a": "third_type"}
]

order = ["first_type","second_type","third_type"]

def orderSort(li):
    res = {}
    for name in order:
        res[name] = [e for e in li if (name==e["a"])]
    return res

print(orderSort(all_values))
```

Output:

```
{
   'first_type': [{'a': 'first_type'}],
   'second_type': [{'a': 'second_type'}, {'a': 'second_type'}],
   'third_type': [{'a': 'third_type'}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below function can be used to extract keys and then update the list

```
all_values = [
{"a": "first_type"},
{"a": "second_type"}, {"a": "second_type"},
{"a": "third_type"}]

sorted_obj={}
for item in all_values:
    element=list( item.values())[0].split('_')[0]
    if  element in sorted_obj.keys():
        sorted_obj[element].append(item)
    else:
        sorted_obj[element]=[item]
```

output

```
{'first': [{'a': 'first_type'}],
 'second': [{'a': 'second_type'}, {'a': 'second_type'}],
 'third': [{'a': 'third_type'}]}
```